# Difference between R::runif() and Rcpp::runif()

Tags: rcpp

I'm learning to use Rcpp in R. Would you please explain me the difference between R::runif() and Rcpp::runif().

I mean 3 questions:

1. Do these 2 functions produce the same stream of random numbers given that we set the same seed before running each of them ?
2. Which function is preferable when using Rcpp ? I mean, it seems to me that the 2 functions produce the same thing, but Rcpp::runif() will run more fastly.
3. How to call Rcpp::runif() in a .R file ? Is it true that the Rcpp::runif() can be called only from a .cpp file and not in R? (I mean, it seems to me that the function Rcpp::runif() is of extensively used to write other C++ functions, then I will import that function by sourcecpp() to use in R)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this question is a duplicate so I may close this but here goes:

1. Yes they do.  The whole point of the RNG interfaces is guaranteeing just that
2. Entirely up to you. Sometimes you want to wrap or use a C API example and you have `R::runif()` for that.  Sometimes you want efficient vector operations for which you have `Rcpp::runif()`.
3. You write a C++ function accessing the C++ API.  Note that not all those functions will be faster than calling what R offers when what R offers is already vectorised. *Your* wrapping of `Rcpp::runif()` will not be much different in performance from calling `stats::runif()`.  You use the C++ accessor in C++ code writing something you cannot easily get from R.

*Edit:* This [Rcpp Gallery post](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/random-number-generation/) has some background and examples.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your help! i would like to clarify something if you don't mind: -@1: about the 2) in your answer, i think it should be the other way around right ? (i.e. "sometimes you want to wrap or use a C API example and you have $RCPP::RUNIF()$). - @2: Could you please kindly tell me what is "stats::" in your answer to the 3) please ? I have searched through internet but I'm not sure what is it. Thank you so much for your help, and also for developing Rcpp, you are just amazing.

Comment: `stats::` denotes the namespace of the `stats` package that comes with R, just like `base`, `utils`, `tools`, `stats4` (!!), `grid`, `lattice`, ...  I used `stats::runif()` to make it explicit, if you type just `runif<Return>` to look at the body of the `runif()` function you see that it comes from `stats`.  Good luck reading up on Rcpp and learning step by step, I hope you continue to find the journey worthwhile.